# Using a Json_encode to then be passed to a data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm struggling to set an array to a data attribute. I can see that it is logging in the DOM with the below image ( a complete mess ):[image]

The attribute data-category is the one in focus. My php that is producing this seems to add ='' if there is a space in the converted php array. This is the php that is converting this over to a json array:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    array_push($arr, $cat->cat_name);
}

data-category="<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>"
```

What is it that I'm missing to convert this to a proper json structure for me to work with in the js.

I'm looking to have an outcome something similar to this:

```
Array [ "Customer Service", "Finance", "HR", "Marketing", "Operations", "Sales", "Technology" ]
```

Comment: that's not going to work. data-category is an HTML attribute. You have to generate valid HTML, which means json_encode() will BREAK your html. e.g. `data-content="<?php echo 'foo' ?>"` will produce `data-content=""foo""` - one set of quotes from the raw html, and one set of quotes from json. You need `echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode(...))`. remember. it might be json, but you're outputting it into an HTML context, not javascript.

Comment: and you get those spaces and `=` because the browser is trying to compensate for your broken html.

Comment: Cheers Marc b, Very informative

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My php that is producing this seems to add ='

That isn't what the PHP is producing.

You are looking at it in a DOM inspector. That shows the results of parsing the HTML to a DOM and then serialising it back to HTML for display.

If you want to look at the output of the PHP then you need to look at **View Source** and not **Inspect Element**.

---

JSON uses `"` to delimit strings.

An HTML attribute value that is delimited by `"` characters will be terminated by `"` characters.

To represent a `"` as data in an HTML attribute value; use `&quot;`.

Run the output of `json_encode` through `htmlspecialchars` before outputting it into the HTML.

```
data-category="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr)); ?>"
```

Comment: You legend I knew i was missing something stupid!! Thanks for your great answer